# EmailJS: Only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, contact-form

I am designing a contact form using React and EmailJS. My problem is that when I input my own values for Name, Email, Phone, or message, the email does not work. When I click the Send Message button without inputting anything into Name, Email, Phone, or message (so it uses default values), then it sometimes works (usually not on the first click of the button, but the second click).

I am not sure how to fix this and would love some help!

```
export default class Contact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { message: '', name: 'Name', email: 'Email', phone: 'Phone' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

      handleSubmit (event) {
        var template_params = {
            "name": "name_value",
            "message": "message_value",
            "phone": "phone_value",
            "email": "email_value"
         }

         var service_id = "default_service";
         var template_id = <TEMPLATE_ID_FROM_EMAILJS_ACCOUNT>;
         window.emailjs.send(service_id, template_id, template_params).then(res => {
             console.log('MESSAGE SENT', res.status);
             alert("Message Sent!");
         }).catch(e => {
             console.log("There was an error", e);
         }); 
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <section className="page-section" id="contact">
                <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">Contact Us</h2>
                    <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Fill in the form below to contact us through email</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" noValidate="noValidate">
                        <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <input className="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name}></input>
                            <p className="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <input className="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email}></input>
                            <p className="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <input className="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.phone}></input>
                            <p className="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="form-group">
                            <textarea className="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message." onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.message}></textarea>
                            <p className="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                        <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button id="sendMessageButton" className="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
        }
}
```

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: No it just resets the form and even though i put in console logs, they do not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about that, but it seems you don"t prevent default behavior of your submit, so your page refreshes, your form is new, and your function not called. 
Try to add

```
event.preventDefault();
```

at the beginning of your handleSubmit function.

Answer (score 0):

[emailJS template setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzfZz.png)

Please click the link to look at the image of EmailJS email body template.

I got into similar issues. You would have to set the emailJS template, same as your input names(name ="name") in JSX using two or three curly braces.(as shown in the attached picture) I've seem a few documents that listed either two or three braces and it seems that both ways work but not all the time. (imo emailJS doesn't seem consistent.) You also have to make sure to "SAVE" the template setting before testing.

```
 <input 
            type ="text" 
            className = "form-input"
            name ="name" 
            placeholder="Name"
            onChange ={updateForm} 
            value = {form.name}
        />
```